# print!() executes after the input is entered

Tags: input, printing, rust

i want to know why the **print!()** macro here executes after the **read_line**

```
// ./src/main.rs
use std::io;

fn main() {
    print!("Input : ");
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    let mut input = String::new();
    stdin.read_line(&mut input).expect("Couldn't read_line");
}
```

This code prints out :

```
   heyy
   Input :
```

But i expect :

```
Input : heyy
```

Comment: Is `print` buffered in Rust? What if you add a new line to the `print` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the Rust documentation here: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.print.html

Specifically, this line:

> "Note that stdout is frequently line-buffered by default so it may be necessary to use io::stdout().flush() to ensure the output is emitted immediately.

This is pretty common when working with the terminal in most languages. `stdout` is buffered on almost all terminals. You can turn it off on some AFAIK but you're better of just either calling flush as they suggest or I believe most terminals will flush their output if you write a new line to it.

Comment: answer obvious duplicate doesn't help the site see https://hackmd.io/mAwiUnSEQauZ9YB-eAdV7g

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved the problem(thanks to [Vaughan Hills](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1554844/vaughan-hilts)) :

```
// Returns the input for a given message - msg
fn input(msg : &str) -> String {
    let mut input = String::new();
    print!("{}", msg);
    io::stdout().flush().unwrap();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut input).unwrap();
    input.trim().to_string()
}
```